# Starting luigi programmatically and not waiting for the job result?

Tags: luigi

So the question is probably fairly simple. I have a job that is supposed to run for ~30 minutes and I don't want my program to wait 30 minutes for the result. I'd like to get a task name or id or something like that and return control to the user so that the user could later query the process state using my program.

https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/695010420105dc836096201a00d2f032f0143b84/luigi/interface.py

Looking at the interface.py I don't see anything relevant. Is it not possible? Or how do I achieve this? Thanks!

ps. If someone could point me at where to look for querying luigi daemon for a task status, i would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few questions here:

1. How to get a task name or id: in the task, you can get this with `self.task_id` You can write this out to a file, a database, a queue etc. in your task's `run` method.
2. How to return control to the user. Should be as simple as backgrounding the task (e.g., follow the luigi command with an `&` in *nix or hit ctrl-z and then type `bg` at the prompt.
3. How to get the task's status- you can have it write out to something while running, but can also check the api at `http://yourluigidhost:8082/api/task_list`

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how to do it from programmatically, i.e. from python? The reason for several questions is because they are kinda related. In the best case scenario I would like to initiate a luigi.build([task], scheduler_host=bla)  and get back not the full debug output, but rather just a Task id and give that back to user. I assume that its not possible from your answer, but would backgrounding be possible? I see no hints of that in the build method. I mean, i can implement a queue, but I was hoping for a more native way.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't use `luigi.build()`, I would just launch the command line process from python and have my luigi pipeline dump the top level task id. I can see where you could sort of break apart the logic used by the `_schedule_and_run()` method `build()` uses and write your own method, that returns the worker before it calls `worker.run()`